# Could not find stanford-parser\.jar jar file at .\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk

I'm new to nltk and seem to be following an outdated tutorial to get started with StanfordDependencyParser in nltk.

I've installed Stanford Core NLP and their English models from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/

However, running the script below returns the following error:

```
could not find stanford-parser\.jar jar file at .\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0
```

Would appreciate any pointers!

Using nltk 3.5 and stanfordcorenlp 4.0.0 with Python 3.7

Script attached below.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser

path_to_jar = '.\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0'
path_to_models_jar = '.\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0-models-english.jar'

dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)

result = dependency_parser.raw_parse('I shot an elephant in my pajamas')
dep = list(result)

for item in dep:
    print(list(item.triples()))
```

Comment: Should `.\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0` be `./stanford-corenlp-4.0.0` ?

Comment: I've tried both; i think the issue is that  my stanford-corenlp folder doesnt have a stanford-parser.jar, i'm not sure if it's missing from my download, or if its something I need to get separately?

Comment: You can try looking into effective pom and search for that in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: stanford-parser.jar seems to have been replaced by stanford-corenlp-4.0.0.jar

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser

path_to_jar = './stanford-corenlp-4.0.0/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0.jar'
path_to_models_jar = './stanford-corenlp-4.0.0/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0-models.jar'

dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(path_to_jar=path_to_jar, path_to_models_jar=path_to_models_jar)
```